# Raw SQL Query working fine in MySQL Workbench, but causing SQLSTATE[22007] when executed through Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to execute a RAW query using `DB::select(DB::raw(..))` in Laravel, but it returns

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect time value

FYI, columns are `TIMESTAMP` data type in `MySQL` db.
That same query, executed in `MySQL` Workbench works fine.

I'm assuming some default settings for Laravel-MySQL communication could be to blame, but I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Tried Google-ing the issue, couldn't find much on the matter, except to change the config/database.php >> mysql >> strict mode to False, since default is True.
I wouldn't want to change config files unless absolutely necessary.
Which brings me to, what exactly does the MySQL Strict Mode refer to?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *That same query, executed in MySQL Workbench works fine.* Enable general log and ensure that the query received by MySQL is really the same.

Comment: The query from the error log works fine in MySQL Workbench. I've copied and executed in workbench the exact sql query that was logged in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post, figured out the issue.

When columns are TIMESTAMP data type, you're supposed to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` instead of `TIMEDIFF()`.

Also, worth mentioning, `TIMEDIFF()` has a limited range of around 35 days or so.

Comment: I've now realized that I didn't mention in my question the use of the timediff/timestampdiff function.